# Как сохранить в бд сообщения отправленные через форму contactform?

Tags: yii2, phpmyadmin

Использую Yii2 basic, при заказе товаров данные сохраняются в phpMyAdmin в таблицах order и order_items

Но также есть и контактная форма. Сейчас отправителю просто приходит уведомление, что сообщение принято и заполненные данные в форме нигде не сохраняются. Что нужно для сохранения в бд? Таблица contact в бд? Какие поля должны быть в ней и как связать их с формой?

ContactForm

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * ContactForm is the model behind the contact form.
 */
class ContactForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;
    public $verifyCode;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
       
           /* Поля обязательные для заполнения */
            [ ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'required'],
            /* Поле электронной почты */
            ['email', 'email'],
            /* Капча */
            ['verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction'=>'index/captcha'],
          /*  ['verifyCode', 'captcha','captchaAction'=>'/contactus/default/captcha'],*/

        ];

    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'verifyCode' => 'Подтвердите код',
            'name' => 'Имя',
            'email' => 'Электронный адрес',
            'subject' => 'Тема',
            'body' => 'Сообщение',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Sends an email to the specified email address using the information collected by this model.
     * @param  string  $email the target email address
     * @return boolean whether the model passes validation
     */
   
      
    public function contact($emailto)
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail']) 
            ->setTo([$this->email => $this->name,'emaildmin@mail.ru' => 'yii2.loc']) 
            ->setSubject('Админ') /* имя отправителя */
            ->setTextBody('Добрый день! Ваше сообщение принято!')->setCharset('UTF-8') /* текст сообщения */

                  
                    

            ->send(); /* функция отправки письма */
        
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

IndexController (contact)

```html
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Andrey
 * Date: 14.05.2016
 * Time: 10:37
 */

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\App\Controller;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use yii\web\Request;



class IndexController extends AppController
{


  public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function actionContact()
    {
        
       // $this->layout = 'contact';
        $this->layout = false;
        

          /* Создаем экземпляр класса */
        $model = new ContactForm();
        /* получаем данные из формы и запускаем функцию отправки contact, если все хорошо, выводим сообщение об удачной отправке сообщения на почту */
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
            return $this->refresh();
        /* иначе выводим форму обратной связи */
        } else {
           return $this->render('contact', [
               'model' => $model,
         ]);
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему он должен сохраняться в БД? Рекомендую для этих целей использовать Active Recodrs в Yii2 и метод модели save(). Подробнее:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#save()-detail

Comment: @Kosmos ну ок. class ContactForm extends ActiveRecord но и что он будет возвращать в public static?Какую таблицу? Где эти записи будут храниться? И как их отправлять админу на почту? Нужна tableName() скорее всего.

Comment: 1. Не понимаю, почему он что-то должен возвращать? Используется обычная процедура. Можете добавить свои статусы, которые будут возвращать, если хотите.
2. Таблица, отвечающая за отправку контактных данных, по умолчанию в Yii2, отсутствует, на сколько мне известно. Поэтому придется создать свою, например 'FeedbackContacts' с полями 'id, name, email, subject, body'. Далее, при вызове экшна перед отправкой на email, например, вызывать метод save(), которая и будет сохранять данные в БД.

Comment: 3. > Где эти записи будут храниться?
На мой взгляд, проще всего будет организовать хранение в БД. А так - исходя из поставленных задач.
4. Для отправки почты в Yii2 есть компонент. Подробнее - https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-mailing/
Можете заменить его на свой, какой вам удобно использовать.
5. Рекомендую для начала ознакомиться с документацией и возможностями фреймворка Yii2.

Comment: @Kosmos вы сами себе противоречите же. У меня уже реализована форма сохранения с ActiveRecord для заказанных товаров и есть таблицы orders и orders_items в бд. Здесь также нужна таблица ContactForm, где  метод public static function tableName() возвращает имя таблицы. Это нужно для подключения к бд.

Comment: в чем именно противоречие? Если все реализовано, вызовите метод по сохранению данных и все. И причем тут таблицы orders и orders_items, если речь идет о 'Сохранении в бд сообщения отправленные через форму contactform'?

Comment: В методе contact($emailto) после строки  if ($this->validate()) { добавьте $this->save();, который будет сохранять данные в БД. Так же объявите имя таблицы и посмотрите, все ли поля соответствуют полям таблицы БД.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал выше @Kosmos, добавьте код сохранения и остальные нужные атрибуты.

Comment: @ ASYOU не все так просто